# bits flags and states

Tags: java, byte, flags, bit, states

I have no idea what this is even called, so I can't really find a question on it.

It's quite simple, I'm writing a program, and my friend gave me some bits for something. (It's hard to explain)

They are:
0x00
0x01
and
0x04

Basically, if a boolean isn't true, I want 0x00 and 0x04 to be added together to make 0004 (4), but if it is true, have 0x01 and 0x04 added to make 0104 (104)

How do I do this? :s

I'm not sure about all the operators, I've tried |, <<, >>, everything that I know, not really knowing what to do, none work.

Answer (score 1):

```
  int falseValue = 0x00;
  int trueValue = 0x01;
  int number = 0x04;
  boolean bool = true;

  int result = ((bool ? trueValue : falseValue) << 8) | number;

  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

`0x00` `0x01` and `0x04` are hexadecimal numbers.you are trying to do hexadecimal addition.

```
String a= Integer.tohexString(0x00);
String b = Integer.toHexString(0x01);
if(true){
    sysout(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseint(a,16)+Integer.parseInt(b,16)));
  }
```